# Date Conversion from String to sql Date in Java giving different output?

Tags: java, date, type-conversion

I have a string form of Date. I have to change it to Sql Date. so for that i have used the following code.

```
String startDate="01-02-2013";
SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mm-yyyy");
java.util.Date date = sdf1.parse(startDate);
java.sql.Date sqlStartDate = new java.sql.Date(date.getTime());
```

when i used the above code and run that. I got the following output.

```
2013-01-01.
```

Here Month is not converted correctly.
Please tell me where is the problem and provide sample code to get correct result?

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and the two `Date` classes. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the first in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 54, accepted):

`mm` is *minutes*. You want `MM` for *months*:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
```

Don't feel bad - this exact mistake comes up a lot.

Comment: this does come up a lot!

Answer (score 9):

`mm` [stands for "minutes"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html). Use `MM` instead:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
```

Answer (score 5):

That is the simple way of converting string into util date and sql date

```
String startDate="12-31-2014";
SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");
java.util.Date date = sdf1.parse(startDate);
java.sql.Date sqlStartDate = new java.sql.Date(date.getTime());
```

Comment: Some comment on the code would be useful.

Answer (score 5):

You need to use `MM` as `mm` stands for **minutes**.

There are two ways of producing **month** pattern.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy"); //outputs month in numeric way, 2013-02-01

SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy"); // Outputs months as follows, 2013-Feb-01
```

Full coding snippet:

```
        String startDate="01-Feb-2013"; // Input String
        SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy"); // New Pattern
        java.util.Date date = sdf1.parse(startDate); // Returns a Date format object with the pattern
        java.sql.Date sqlStartDate = new java.sql.Date(date.getTime());
        System.out.println(sqlStartDate); // Outputs : 2013-02-01
```

Answer (score 1):

While using the date formats, you may want to keep in mind to always use `MM` for months and `mm` for minutes. That should resolve your problem.