# Converting fromTextView to date android

Tags: android, date, textview

I'm working on a project in Android Studio 1.5.1. and I have
TextView startDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.newevent_startdate);

now I need to use the value of startDate but as a type of java.sql.Date. how can I convert this?

Comment: It depends on the format of the date and you didn't specify it but [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10413350/date-conversion-from-string-to-sql-date-in-java-giving-different-output) should have all the pieces you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose if you have a startDate in your `TextView` with this format "yyyy-mm-dd" i.e 2016-01-26, then you can parse that to Date object using below code.

```
String startDateString = startDate.getText().toString() ;  // where startDate is your TextView
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");  // same date format as your TextView supports
try {  
    Date date = simpleDateFormat.parse(startDateString); // parses the string date to get a date object  
} catch (ParseException e) {  
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block  
    e.printStackTrace();  
}
```